# transactions are performed sequentially by the blockchain, but how are the waiting times managed?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, blockchain, pending-transactions

I have a booking dapp where you can make reservations and call the bookRequest method. If many users call this method, it is not possible to know the order in which they will be performed and therefore it is not possible to know the order of confera. But how is it possible to manage this mechanism? A user cannot wait too long to receive the booking confirmation. How can I avoid pending transactions?

Answer (score 2):

The one who mines the block decides the sequence of its transactions. Usually the order is decided by the transactions' gas prices (default logic for most miners). In that case, users may influence it by "speeding up" the transaction, meaning: re-broadcast the transaction with a higher gas price.